# Concatenate as string value between cells

Tags: excel

I've got a sheet as follow:

```
C1   C2   C3    C4     Result
A     B    C    001     A_B_C_1
```

The 'Result' column is generated by concatenating from cell C1-C4. However, my desired output is  A_B_C_001 rather than  A_B_C_1. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: What is the cell format of `c4`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If C4 is text: 
`=CONCATENATE(C1,"_",C2,"_",C3,"_",C4)`

if C4 is a number: 
`=CONCATENATE(C1,"_",C2,"_",C3,"_",TEXT(C4,"00#"))`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your C4 Column cell is in `text` format. After that you can do this.

```
=CONCATENATE(A2,"_",B2,"_",C2,"_",D2)
```